# How to run emacs in batch mode and have it automatically follow GIT Repository Links

Tags: emacs, batch-processing

I am trying to run Emacs on Verilog source file that are Git Controlled. I also set emacs to follow symbolic links. But despite that I get this -

```
    emacs -batch real_wrap.sv -f verilog-auto -f save-buffer -l verilog-mode  --eval="(set vc-follow-symlinks t)"
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/auctex.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/focus-init.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/gnuplot-init.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/php-mode-init.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/po-mode-init.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/preview-latex.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/rpm-spec-mode-init.el (source)...
    Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/rpmdev-init.el (source)...
    Loading vc-git...
    Symbolic link to Git-controlled source file; follow link? (yes or no)
```

Emacs is still getting into interactive mode and asking whether (or not) to follow link. Any thoughts on how not to have Emacs do this ? The version of Emacs is 23.1.1

Comment: what does this question has to do with verilog?

Comment: I just wanted to inform that the command I am using is emacs verilog mode in batch mode. so most likely verilog developers might have come across this issue ???

Comment: this is a vc-git issue or incorrect configuration.  Please remove the verilog tag. try to use 'setq' instead of set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Serge has pointed out in the comments, your mistake is using `set` instead of `setq`.

The default value of `vc-follow-symlinks` is the symbol `ask`.  Therefore `(set vc-follow-symlinks t)` is equivalent to `(setq ask t)` and has no effect at all on the value of `vc-follow-symlinks`, but rather sets a value for a variable named `ask`.

The "q" in `setq` means "quoted", as its symbol argument is not *evaluated*, whereas the argument to `set` does get evaluated.  You could manually quote the argument with `(set 'vc-follow-symlinks t)` but in practice you would invariably use `setq`.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the details! Yes, I realized that I had a type. Serge's and your suggestion worked!